# Filter function for phone number search in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Help with filter function!

I have a table with  phone number and name as columns.
The JSON object would look something like this :
Details = [
{PN : '123-456-7890',
NAME : 'PERSON A',
},{
PN: '192-453-7655',
NAME: 'PERSON B',
}
]

I need to search on keyup and filter the data. The user can search in any of these patterns:

xxxxxxxxxx,
xxx-xxx-xxxx,
xxx-xxxxxxx,
xxxxxx-xxxx.

and still needs to get the data having xxx-xxx-xxxx as phone number in the table. Search should start as soon as the keyup triggers.

I tried using match and test methods, but couldn't make connection between search input, regex and the elements from table.

Can anyone suggest how I can tackle this situation?

Comment: share code atempted till now if possible a stackblitz!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this regex -

```
/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$|^\d{3}-\d{7}$|^\d{6}-\d{4}|^\d{10}$/
```

Angular Code -

```
matchNumber(){
  var str = "12311111455"; 
  var res = str.match(/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$|^\d{3}-\d{7}$|^\d{6}-\d{4}|^\d{10}$/);
  if(res.length > 0){
   console.log('Matched);
  }}
```

**Valid Numbers**

1. 1234567890
2. 123-456-7890
3. 123-4567890
4. 123456-7890

**Invalid Numbers**

1. 123453647564756876
2. 111223-234234

Check DEMO  -
[Check Valid Numbers](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-shockley-3pklug?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)